# Access variable in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying process an arraylist using arbitrary number of worker threads.  I would like to keep track of how many items each worker thread has processed and terminate them after a certain number.  Would declaring a variable for counter inside the worker thread class and checking on that counter be a valid approach?

```
.
.
Thread t = new Thread();
t.start
while(true){
 if(t.counter >= 5){
  return;
 }
}
.
.

class Thread{
    int counter = 0;
    public void run {
        while(true){
         do something....
         counter++;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Busy-waiting (`while (true) {...}`) is a very bad idea, as this will take 100% or as much as possible of one CPU, reducing the availability of your worker thread.

Comment: You will also need to make the `counter` variable `volatile` as in: `volatile int counter = 0;`. Otherwise there is no guarantee that your main thread will ever see a change in the variable `counter`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys I decided to change my implementation to passes the value of iterations a worker thread should iterate as a parameter in the constructor of the worker thread so checking is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
int counter = 0;

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run {
        while(true){
            doSomething...
            counter++
        }
    }

});
t.start();

while(true){
    if(counter >= 5){
        return;
    }
}
```

As an answer to your question... i do not know of any way to access the runnable of another thread. There might be, but the above code will work just fine hopefully.